# discord.py on member join , give a role command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I made a command that can set a on member join, give role command where it stores it into a json file. But when someone joins it comes up with the error: return self._roles.get(role_id) TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Here is my code:

```
with open('join_roles.json', 'r') as f:
  join_roles = json.load(f)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = member.guild
  print(join_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
  role = member.guild.get_role(join_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
  await member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def joinrole(ctx, role):
  join_roles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.split()
  with open('join_roles.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(join_roles, f)
  await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f':white_check_mark:| Member join role set to {role}!', color=0x2596be))
```

Comment: Can you show the `join_roles.json`?

Comment: Yeah sure:
     {"865806960997826571": ["<@&869075604077707266>"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `join_roles.get(str(guild.id))` returns a `list` and that won't work on a [`guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_role#discord.Guild.get_role). This could point to your json data being displayed like so:

```json
{
    "GuildID": ["RoleID"]
}
```

Due to `join_roles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.split()` which puts a list into the json data. A much better solution is to use a [RoleConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=roleconverter#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter) which returns [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role) this would allow roles by: ID, Role mention and by Role name.

```py
with open('join_roles.json', 'r') as f:
  join_roles = json.load(f)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = member.guild
  print(join_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
  role = member.guild.get_role(join_roles.get(str(guild.id)))
  await member.add_roles(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def joinrole(ctx, role):
  role = await commands.RoleConverter().convert(ctx, role)
  join_roles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.id
  with open('join_roles.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(join_roles, f)
  await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f':white_check_mark:| Member join role set to {role.name}!', color=0x2596be))
```

Comment: You can also just change the params in the command function to `async def joinrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):` and then dont need the line after it

Comment: Also, would you know how to do the same thing with channels?

Comment: @QuantumCode https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=channelconverter#discord.ext.commands.TextChannelConverter